# Why doesn't java_binary propagate runtime dependencies to java_test

Tags: java, bazel, bazel-java

I wrote a small application and used *java_binary* as follows:

```
java_binary(
    name = "MyCommand",
    srcs = [
        "MyCommand.java",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//src/main/java/com/example/two",
    ],
)
```

It depends on a `java_library` target //src/main/java/com/example/two

I then wrote a `java_test` as follows:

```
java_test(
    name = "TestMyCommand",
    size = "small",
    srcs = [
        "TestMyCommand.java",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":MyCommand",
    ],
)
```

The test is pretty simple and just does `new MyCommand()`.

This unfortunately fails quickly with a `ClassDefNotFoundException` with a class file found in `//src/main/java/com/example/two`. Setting a breakpoint it looks like that library is not included in the ClassPath.

**HOWEVER**, if I change my `java_test` to depend on a `java_library` **THEN** the transitive dependency of `//src/main/java/com/example/two` is included.

I could not find anything in the documentation explaining why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `java_binary` is a "binary" rule, i.e., it outputs an executable, or another way, it's typically a "terminal" or "root" rule. So it doesn't pass along the info to add its deps to the final classpath, because it doesn't typically expect to be in the dependencies[1] of other targets (even `java_test`).

You could refactor the BUILD file so that `MyCommand.java` is in a `java_library`, and the `java_test` and the `java_binary` targets depend on that:

```
java_binary(
    name = "MyCommandMain",
    runtime_deps = [":MyCommand"],
    main_class = "com.example.one.MyCommand",
)

java_library(
    name = "MyCommand",
    srcs = [
        "MyCommand.java",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//src/main/java/com/example/two",
    ],
)
```

---

1: But you do sometimes see things like this:

```
# or other kinds of binary rules (cc_binary, py_binary, etc)
java_binary(
  name = "my_java_bin",
  ...,
)

sh_binary(
  name = "my_shell_script",
  srcs = ["script.sh"],
  data = [":my_java_bin"],
)
```

and `script.sh` runs `my_java_bin` as part of whatever it's accomplishing. The difference here is that `my_shell_script` is using the whole binary, rather than programming against code within it.

Comment: how does the sh_binary work if it does not get the transitive dependencies also ? It needs  them for runtime... Is there a flag to control this? I find this distinction strange...

Comment: One of the outputs of a binary rule is its so-called "runfiles", the files needed to run the executable. The sh_binary receives those files (i.e., bazel sets up all those files in the sh_binary's exec root for `bazel run`), and in the case of java_binary, those are a wrapper script that invokes java with the right arguments and jars, and the collection of jars for the application. How the java rules decide what should be on the class path (compile time classpath, runtime classpath, or both) is separate.

Comment: Regarding a flag, what behavior specifically are you looking to change?

Comment: Propagate the runtime deps like java_library

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is working as intended (e.g. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11705 and https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12836), but maybe `java_test` depending on a `java_binary` is worth some consideration, so feel free to open a feature request: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.yml